# What's the point of full configurations in .tfstate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I've gone through some basic reading:
https://blog.gruntwork.io/an-introduction-to-terraform-f17df9c6d180
and
https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa

So I understand that .tfstate tells the terraform CLI which resources it's actually responsible for managing. But couldn't that be done more minimally with a list of ID's?

Why does .tfstate need to contain full configurations of all resources, if `terraform refetch` is run implicitly before `terraform apply`?

Would the fetch not get complete information from the infrastructure? And then that could be used to do the diff etc...

I suppose if you get complete information every time, you might as well record it. But I'm wondering if it's a necessary step. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. But I don't quite understand. Would something special happen if someone else changes it outside Terraform? I assumed it would pick up whatever the real state was and just work from there

Comment: It needs to be able to tell what has changed at any point and to do that it needs to know the state of things. Your state file is just a snapshot from the last time an apply was ran. As for why the state file isn't just a list of resource IDs and only hold the full state ephemerally instead of writing that to the state file, largely a case of simplicity. This way Terraform can build the graph entirely from the state file and the state file just needs to be refreshed before running.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you care whether the state file contains all of the information?